# glm in well separated groups does not find the coefficient and p-values

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm

Disclaimer: I am very new to glm binomial.

However, this to me sounds very basic however glm brings back something that either is incorrect or I don't know how to interpret it.

First I was using my primary data and was getting errors, then I tried to replicate the error and I see the same thing: I define two columns, indep and dep and glm results does not make sense, to me at least...

Any help will be really appreciated. I have a second question on handling NAs in my glm but first I wish to take care of this :(

```
set.seed(100)
x <- rnorm(24, 50, 2)
y <- rnorm(24, 25,2)
j <- c(rep(0,24), rep(1,24))
d <- data.frame(dep= as.factor(j),indep = c(x,y))
mod <- glm(dep~indep,data = d, family = binomial)
summary(mod)
```

Which brings back:

```
Call:
glm(formula = dep ~ indep, family = binomial, data = d)

Deviance Residuals: 
       Min          1Q      Median          3Q         Max  
-9.001e-06  -7.612e-07   0.000e+00   2.110e-08   1.160e-05  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)     92.110 168306.585   0.001        1
indep           -2.409   4267.658  -0.001        1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 6.6542e+01  on 47  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 3.9069e-10  on 46  degrees of freedom
AIC: 4

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 25
Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 25
```

What is happening? I see the warning but in this case these two groups are really separated...

Barplot of the random data: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Win8H.png)

Comment: You want your dependent variable on the left hand side of the formula

Comment: Sorry updated still get the same error, you were right my naming for dep indep was incorrect but I was consistent. I have updated to have the right column names. Thank you great catch. Any thoughts on the error?

Comment: You have complete separation (i.e., `indep` perfectly separates `dep` into 0 and 1), so the maximum likelihood estimate of the coefficient for `indep` is essentially infinity. You might find [this](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqwhat-is-complete-or-quasi-complete-separation-in-logisticprobit-regression-and-how-do-we-deal-with-them/) and [this](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqwhat-is-complete-or-quasi-complete-separation-in-logisticprobit-regression-and-how-do-we-deal-with-them/) helpful.